# angularjs $localStorage is undefined, but was defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-local-storage

I am using angularjs's `$localStorage` function, but currently it does not want to be included for some reason.  I know that `$localStorage` works, as I have used it in other controllers in the same webapp.  I also know that this is not a spelling error, as I checked that repeatedly, and I also know that the `$localStorage` variable `curAllianceCol` is defined, as I use this exact same variable in a later controller.

Any help is appreciated, and if (for some reason that I don't know) you cannot use `$localStorage` in an angularjs directive, please tell me so that I can make a workaround.

Relevant JS:

```
window.fires = angular.module('FIRES', ['ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router', 'ngStorage']);
//(...Non-relevant code..)
window.fires.directive('fieldDirective', ['ScoutService', '$localStorage', function(ScoutService, $interval, $localStorage) {
    var $scope = this;
    $scope.sServ = ScoutService;
    console.log($localStorage.curAllianceCol); //This is line 177, just for reference between the error message and this file
    $scope.col = $localStorage.curAllianceCol;
    //(...Non-relevant code..)
}]);
```

Error message I recieve:

> "Error: $localStorage is undefined
>   @http://192.168.250.111:8080/js/fires.js:177:2
>   invoke@http://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3965:14
>   registerDirective/http://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5716:33
>   forEach@http://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:325:9
>   registerDirective/<@http://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5714:13
>   invoke@http://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3965:14
>   createInjector/instanceCache.$injector<@http://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3807:20
>   getService@http://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3929:39
>   addDirective@http://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6804:41
>   collectDirectives@http://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6231:1
>   compileNodes@http://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6080:22
>   compileNodes@http://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6096:15
>   compileNodes@http://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6096:15
>   compileNodes@http://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6096:15
>   compile@http://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6017:15
>   $ViewDirectiveFill/<.compile/<@http://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:3893:20
>   nodeLinkFn@http://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6752:13
>   compositeLinkFn@http://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6146:13
>   publicLinkFn@http://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6042:30
>   updateView@http://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:3839:23
>   $ViewDirective/directive.compile/http://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:3801:11
>   $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13093:15
>   transitionTo/$state.transition<@http://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:3218:11
>   qFactory/defer/deferred.promise.then/wrappedCallback@http://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11682:31
>   qFactory/ref/<.then/<@http://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11768:26
>   $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12811:16
>   $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12623:15
>   $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12915:13
>   done@http://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8450:34
>   completeRequest@http://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8664:7
>   createHttpBackend/http://192.168.250.111:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8603:1
>   "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if your code is correct but, have you tried removing the `$interval` or adding the appropriate dependency since that's the second parameter passed into your directive which would make `$localStorage` (your 3rd parameter) `undefined`.

**Example without $interval**

```
window.fires.directive('fieldDirective', ['ScoutService', '$localStorage', function(ScoutService, $localStorage) {
    var $scope = this;
    $scope.sServ = ScoutService;
    console.log($localStorage.curAllianceCol); //This is line 177, just for reference between the error message and this file
    $scope.col = $localStorage.curAllianceCol;
    //(...Non-relevant code..)
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my oblivious mistake.  I was using that before, but forgot to remove that from the function declaration.  It is now working perfectly fine.